# show item/article list in category tree in joomla k2 module or component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

its posibble to get view like this (with module or component)  in joomla k2?

1. parent category 1

   - child category 1.1

     - item 1.1.1
     - item 1.1.2
     - item 1.1.3
   - child category 1.2

     - item 1.2.1
     - item 1.2.2
     - item 1.2.3
   - child category 1.3

     - item 1.3.1
     - item 1.3.2
     - item 1.3.3
2. parent category 2

   - child category 2.1

     - item 2.1.1
     - item 2.1.2
     - item 2.1.3
   - child category 2.2

     - item 2.2.1
     - item 2.2.3
     - item 2.2.3
   - child category 2.3

     - item 2.3.1
     - item 2.3.2
     - item 2.3.3
3. parent category 3

   - child category 3.1

     - item 3.1.1
     - item 3.1.2
     - item 3.1.3
   - child category 3.2

     - item 3.2.1
     - item 3.2.2
     - item 3.2.3
   - child category 3.3

     - item 3.3.1
     - item 3.3.2
     - item 3.3.3

what i mean is like this

[click to see image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3PfKryCuyZkN3dMajNTUlo0LU0/edit?usp=drive_web)

anyone can help? please.. you will save my live   :cheer:

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this example of menus drop down if you want to use for catagories use appropriate tables (for radios use **level field of table as main** in ul,ol indteadof select ):-

```
<?php $db = JFactory::getDBO();
      $query = "SELECT m.id, m.title,m.level,mt.menutype FROM #__menu AS m INNER JOIN #__menu_types AS mt ON mt.menutype = m.menutype WHERE mt.menutype = m.menutype AND m.published = '1' ORDER BY mt.menutype,m.level";
      $db->setQuery($query);
      $rows = $db->loadObjectList();?>

      <select id="setredirct" name="settings[]">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---Default---</option>
        <?php foreach ($rows as $row) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" >
          <?php echo '<b>'.$row->menutype.'</b>';
          if ($row->level == 1) { echo '-';}
          if($row->level == 2) { echo '--';}
          if($row->level == 3) { echo '---';}
          if($row->level == 4) { echo '----';}
          if($row->level == 5) { echo '-----';}
            echo $row->title;?>
        </option>
      <?php }?>
      </select>
```

Comment: thanks before for your answer :) but i think there is missunderstanding about what im trying to ask.. i want to know how to get list item(title and image) at each child category wih block of parent category (parent category not have item, just have child category). not for menu module but for content module or component in k2. sorry before for my list format on my question make my question look ambigue. btw im not ask about dash '-' :D

Comment: what i mean is like this :D https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3PfKryCuyZkN3dMajNTUlo0LU0/edit?usp=drive_web